# i successfully log in but can only access the site after 2nd try

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-security

I copied this guy's tutorial exactly and got it running in IntelliJ and Spring 2.1.7:
https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d

I think I had to make the html file "/admin/home.html" myself because he didn't have that for some reason.

When I first successfully log in I'm immediately redirected to:
http://localhost:8080/error

But then i can manually go to /admin/home or if I log in again I'm automatically redirected there.  In SecurityConfiguration.java I believe this line says I should get redirected there:
.defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")

But for some reason the the first time I log in I'm redirected to the error page.  Anybody know why?

Comment: Please check server error and access logs for details (403 and 500 error codes especially)

Comment: `{"timestamp":"2019-09-02T10:39:19.724+0000","status":999,"error":"None","message":"No message available"}`

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 10:39:19 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`

Comment: okay i enabled tomcat error log, here's the last 3 lines in access_log.2019-09-02.log:
`0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Sep/2019:05:44:24 -0500] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 1718`
`0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Sep/2019:05:44:31 -0500] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -`
`0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Sep/2019:05:44:31 -0500] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 500 116
`

Answer (score 0):

I added the word true here and now it works:
`.defaultSuccessUrl("/tasks", true)`

I don't know why.  I finally found 123's answer here:
[Spring security login always lands in an error page with no message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660763/spring-security-login-always-lands-in-an-error-page-with-no-message)

This will by magic to me until I understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your answer, if you set `.defaultSuccessUrl("/tasks", true)` you will always be redirected to "/tasks" after successful login.
The the signature of that method is `defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl, boolean alwaysUse)`.
If `alwaysUse` is `true`, then `defaultSuccessUrl` will always be used as the redirect URL after successful login.
If `alwaysUse` is false (default), then you will be redirected to the secure page you accessed before logging in. For example, if you go to "/home" and that page is secured then you will be redirected to the login page. Once you log in successfully then spring security will remember that the page you initially tried to access is "/home" and redirect you back there.