# Spring boot security throws error with status 999 "No message avaiable"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, http-error

I am writing a car rent web app using Spring-boot, Spring-security, Hibernate, MySQL, JSP, JSTL, AspectJ in Intellij. I use JDBC authentication to login users. The problem is: if I login for the first time, I got an error of status `999`, type `None`, with message: `Message not available`, second logging passes normally.

I've read that it might be Spring Security not finding declared folders in WebSecurity configuration. I tried many ant matchers, finally I left only `/css/**` and `/js/**`, since both are being read properly on my page, but the result was the same- error status 999.

Is it the source of the problem? Could anyone point what I am doing wrong?

SecurityConfiguration.class

```
package com.doszke.CarRent.web;

import com.doszke.CarRent.reflect.annotations.AccessLevel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Value("${carrent.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${carrent.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/registerSuccess").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAuthority(AccessLevel.USER).anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(AccessLevel.ADMIN).anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                        .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                    .usernameParameter("login")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**");//, "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }


}
```

my resource and webapp tree:

[image]

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660763/spring-security-login-always-lands-in-an-error-page-with-no-message] has solutions to this

Comment: I think this works for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029340/spring-security-redirects-to-page-with-status-code-999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029340/spring-security-redirects-to-page-with-status-code-999)

Answer (score -1):

try add

`.antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()`

work for me.