# Spring security redirects to page with status code 999

Tags: java, spring-security

After successful login spring redirects to `/error` page with the following content

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1586002411175,
  "status" : 999,
  "error" : "None",
  "message" : "No message available"
}
```

I'm using `spring-boot 2.2.4`

### My config:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup=1
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration/**").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .headers()
                        .defaultsDisabled()
                        .cacheControl()
                    .and()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/errors/403")
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/log") // I don't want to use force redirect here
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .rememberMe()
                    .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                    .key("myKey");

    }

    // ...
}
```

### Note:

Turns out that error is caused by failed request to one of my static resources. Login page has `<script src="/resources/my-js-file.js"></script>` that is missing in the project.
I can fix this by removing missing resource import, but the problem can reappear in future so it's not a fix.

### How can I prevent this from happening?

I know I can force redirect to starting page with `.defaultSuccessUrl("/log", true)` but I don't want this.
Also I want redirect to work properly despite of any not found resources.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time I figured out what's happening.

So spring can't find one of static resources that is used on login page. But instead of returning status `404` for this resource it tries to render error page and forwards request to `/error`. Then spring security denies this request because user is not authorized. It saves `/error` request to session (for redirecting after successful login) and redirects user to login page.

Of course user can't see this redirect because status `302` returns for request that is done in background. But the main issue is `/error` request saved in session.

Then user logins successfully and spring checks session for this attribute and makes redirect to `/error` page. By default [spring assumes that you have such page somewhere in static resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages). If you doesn't have this page you will see this weird error with status code 999.

### Solution 1

Ignore `/error` page in security config:

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/error");
```

So this request will not be saved to session for user redirection after successful login. You will see that on login page status code of request to static resource will change from `302` to `404`.

### Solution 2

Ignore part of spring boot autoconfig:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

This gives same result but disables some beans from config `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` so be careful.

Comment: In my case the missing of /images/favicon.ico was an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issu, *authenticated* or *permitAll* requestMatchers paths have status code 200 in right case, but with exceptions cases : the 404 or 500 are transformed to 401. After investigation, I found same solutions as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61029341/2260704
But I think is rather a workaround, after discussion with others developers, I understand that the problem was in my SecurityConfiguration definition with a problem in the paths rules logic.

Rule to remember: in Spring Security all paths are deny by default.

You must give requestMatcher specific paths and a general case with .anyRequest(). In this way, anyRequest support the "/error" !

Good rules, "/error" included in **anyRequest**, (404 are 404, and 500 are 500) :

```
.requestMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated());
```

Wrong rules:

```
.requestMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried commenting every stylesheet link to see which one was causing the error. It was my custom css file. The problem was that in my css file I had an url for an image that didn't exist and also another @import statement that was wrong. After commenting these, everything worked fine.